# Objective-C – Smart programming with dependencies

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

I have an iOS application that parses xml data from the web. I've setup it to parse some xml tags for me and then display some information in the application.

I do not own the xml data so it's not unlikely that the xml tags could change without my knowledge and then rendering my iOS application useless because I'm not able to parse the data with the wrong xml tags.

So instead of having the application crashing when (if) they change xml tags I was thinking of having the application send an e-mail in the background alerting that the xml tags have changed. Or something like that. Is that possible to do or is it even a smart solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you parse the XML file in your server side using any technology that you prefer, and provide your controlled XML file to your iOS application. That way you will have the full control over the XML tags that your application expects! If the other party changes the tags, you just re-write your server side program to handle the changes gracefully!